# Class 'HTML' not found, I have tried everything

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have done the composer require `illuminate\html` and into my `composer.json` file it puts

```
 "illuminate/html|: "^5.0"
```

Then I went to the `config/app.php` file and added in the lines to the providers

```
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and the aliases

```
    'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class
```

why am I still receiving  class HTML not found.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: You should include the exact error message as it is.

Comment: `illuminate/html` is deprecated, use `laravelcollective/html`.

Answer (score 3):

Class names are case-sensitive. You registered the `Html` facade, but are using it as `HTML`.

Change one of them to match the other and you'll be fine.

---

**P.S.** You're aliasing the `FormFacade` twice. Be sure to correctly alias the `HtmlFacade`.

Comment: That's not correct, class names are not case sensitive in PHP.

Comment: @Bogdan - Static ones aren't. Aliases (the way they are implemented) are.

Comment: That true, my mistake. I thought your statement was more general.

Comment: Okay that worked kind of. so I have 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      {{ Html::script('js/script.js') }}
      {{ Html::style('css/style.css') }}
    </head>
    <body>
      {{ Html::link('http://google.com/', 'goog') }}
      {{ Html::ul($list) }}
     </body>

and now it is returning literally <script src="http://localhost/js/script.js"></script> <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/css/style.css"> <a href="http://google.com/">goog</a> <ul><li>banna</li><li>pear</li><li>apple</li></ul>
    </html>

Comment: Okay I found what was wrong I need to type {!! Html~ !!}